# Save Microsoft Word 2010 document as PDF and preserving inter-document bookmarks

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2010, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat, hyperlink

Using Microsoft Word 2010, on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, *without* any PDF-generation COM add-ins/add-ons installed:

Is it possible to save documents that have hyperlinks pointing to bookmarks in other documents preserved if all documents are saved as PDF?  By "preserved" I mean that opening up the resulting PDF document inside Acrobat Reader and clicking on the link will open up the destination *and* scroll down and position the resulting document view on that bookmarked location?

I think the answer is no, so this is to get confirmation on that. Here is why I think it is "no":

When I open up the resulting PDF file in Acrobat Reader DC, and click on the links, the links do not actually open up the destination PDF document at the destination bookmark. They only just open up the destination pdf document to the first page.

The links in the originating document are formatted as follows (this is from the Edit Hyperlink dialog on the originating .docx file):

[image: Insert Hyperlink]

The some_destination_doc.docx was then saved as a PDF file, and using the Save AS, PDF, Options, Create bookmarks using, Word bookmarks option:

[image: Save As PDF Options Window]

Note that I do not have any COM Addins for PDF generation installed, such as what presumably comes bundled with the [Adobe Acrobat DC](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/how-to/word-excel-ppt-to-pdf-converter.html) non-free application. This question is just to find out if it is possible to get this to work using a "stock" install of Office 2010.

Comment: What is the resulting link that you get from using the create bookmark wizard to insert that link? Like, `some_destination_doc.pdf#bookmark-header` for example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Word 2013:

[image]

Note that the heading "third page" is just a random heading I made on the third page of a blank document. The link worked for me in Sumatra PDF and Adobe.

Comment: I have found that this works only within a single PDF file generated from a single Word document in Word 2010. But, I am specifically trying to make it so that links in one PDF file that point to another PDF document will open up that other PDF file *and* view that particular location in that second PDF file. Very much like an HTML anchor would work but in HTML pages.